# Nested loops with cython for image processing

Tags: python, parallel-processing, cython, gil

I'm trying to iterate over a 2D image containing floating-point depth data, it has a somewhat normal resolution (640, 480), but python has been too slow, so I've been trying to optimize the problem by using cython.

I've tried to move the looping to other functions, shifting around the `nogil` statement, didn't seem to work, after reworking the problem, I was able to get a portion of it working.  But this last part is escaping me to no avail.

I've attempted to get rid of python objects from the `prange()` loop by moving them to the `with gil` section beforehand, hence:

```py
cdef int[:] w_list = array.array(range(0, w_inc, interpolation))
```

instead of

```py
for r in range(0, w_inc, interpolation):
```

but the error persists

My code works in two parts:

1. The `split_data()` method subsections the image into `num` quadrants that are stored in a 3D array  `bits`. These are use to make splitting up the work to multiple thread/processes easier. This part works okay.

```py
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef split_data(double[:, :] frame, int h, int w, int num):
    cdef double[:, :, :] bits = np.zeros(shape=(num, h // num, w // num), dtype=float)
    cdef int c_count = os.cpu_count()
    cdef int i, j, k

    for i in prange(num, nogil=True, num_threads=c_count):
        for j in prange(h // num):
            for k in prange(w // num):
                bits[i, j, k] = frame[i * (h // num) + j, i * (w // num) + k]

    return bits
```

2. The `scatter_data()` method takes the `bits` array from the previous function and then creates another 3D array with length `num` where `num` is the length of `bits`, called `points` which is a series of 3D coordinates representing valid depth points. It then uses `prange()` to extract the valid depth data from each of these `bits` and stores them into `points`

```py
@cython.cdivision(True)
@cython.boundscheck(False)
cpdef scatter_data(double[:, :] depths, object validator=None,
                         int h=-1, int w=-1, int interpolation=1):

    # Handles if h or w is -1 (default)
    if h < 0 or w < 0:
        h = depths.shape[0] if h < 0 else h
        w = depths.shape[1] if w < 0 else w

    cdef int max_num = w * h
    cdef int c_count = os.cpu_count()
    cdef int h_inc = h // c_count, w_inc = w // c_count

    cdef double[:, :, :] points = np.zeros(shape=(c_count, max_num, 3), dtype=float)

    cdef double[:, :, :] bits = split_data(depths, h, w, c_count)

    cdef int count = 0
    cdef int i, r, c

    cdef int[:] w_list = array.array(range(0, w_inc, interpolation))
    cdef int[:] h_list = array.array(range(0, h_inc, interpolation))

    for i in prange(c_count, nogil=True, num_threads=c_count):
        count = 0
        for r in w_list:
            for c in h_list:
                if depths[c, r] != 0:
                    points[i, count, 0] = w - r
                    points[i, count, 1] = c
                    points[i, count, 2] = depths[c, r]
                    count = count + 1

    points = points[:count]

    return points
```

and for completeness
3. Here are my import statements

```py
import cython
from cython.parallel import prange
from cpython cimport array
import array
cimport numpy as np
import numpy as np
import os
```

When compiling the code I keep getting error messages something along the lines of:

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef int[:] w_list = array.array(range(0, w_inc, interpolation))
    cdef int[:] h_list = array.array(range(0, h_inc, interpolation))

    for i in prange(c_count, nogil=True, num_threads=c_count):
        count = 0
        for r in w_list:
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

data_util/cy_scatter.pyx:70:17: Iterating over Python object not allowed without gil
```

and

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef int[:] w_list = array.array(range(0, w_inc, interpolation))
    cdef int[:] h_list = array.array(range(0, h_inc, interpolation))

    for i in prange(c_count, nogil=True, num_threads=c_count):
        count = 0
        for r in w_list:
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

data_util/cy_scatter.pyx:70:17: Coercion from Python not allowed without the GIL
```

and

```
Error compiling Cython file:
------------------------------------------------------------
...
    cdef int[:] w_list = array.array(range(0, w_inc, interpolation))
    cdef int[:] h_list = array.array(range(0, h_inc, interpolation))

    for i in prange(c_count, nogil=True, num_threads=c_count):
        count = 0
        for r in w_list:
                ^
------------------------------------------------------------

data_util/cy_scatter.pyx:70:17: Converting to Python object not allowed without gil
```

Is there a way to do this?  And if so, how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just want to iterate by index rather than by iterating over a Python iterator:

```
for ri in range(w_list.shape[0]):
    r = w_list[ri]
```

This is somewhere where best practice in Python differs from best practice in Cython - Cython only accelerates iterating over numeric loops. The way you're trying to do it will fall back to being a Python iterator which is both slower, and requires the GIL.

Comment: Okay, so is there a difference between this and using `for r in range(0, w_inc, interpolation):`? Why does yours work, and mine fail?

Comment: It looks like Cython can cope with 1 or 2 arguments to `range`, but hasn't created a special case for the three argument version. I'm not sure if there's a good reason for that or if it's just not been done yet (I can't think of one but it may be something subtle).